# Must "N" be natural in the definiton of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition

In the below definiton of limit, Kenneth Ross does not specify what type of fixed number "N" should be?

Does this mean that "N" can be an imaginary number?

Doesn't it makes more sense for N to be a natural number just like the domain of the sequence?

[image: Def of Limit/Convergence]

Comment: $N$ is a natural number.

Comment: Real or rational, or integer, will work.

Comment: What is the definition of a sequence in the book? Also please give the title of the book, so that we can all know what you are talking about.

Comment: Kenneth Ross (Real Analysis) pdf here:https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/ixbzgb46cf85ri/j0eaxrf238r4rl

Comment: The definitionof a sequence in that text states that a sequence is a function whose domain is a set of the form $\{n \in \Bbb{Z} : n \ge m\}$ for some $m$. The discussion after the definition of a limit says that it is sufficent to take $N$ to be a positive integer on the basis of the Archimedean property (which is a property of **real numbers**, not complex numbers). The book has not defined the notion of complex number. Your question seems specious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the term "sequence" implies that n is an integer. Otherwise he would have called s a function.

And you can't compare $n > N$ if $N$ is anything other than a real number, and the choice of whether it is real or rational or integer is inconsequential, because $n$ is an integer.

Comment: So shouldn't the definition specify "real number" instead of just "number"?

Comment: No, it only has to be something that is comparable to an integer.  For example, if $N=\pi$ is found to satisfy the definition, then $N = 3142/1000$ will also satisfy it, as will just $N=4$.

Comment: @Bob: Often in mathematics texts, things like this are left implicit. Here, you just have to infer that because “$n>i$” is meaningless, $N$ has to be a real number.